# Generate partial subsets in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Confession: this is for a class.

I am trying to generate all subsets of length 1 - length(full set), but they must be in order.

So, with an input of (4,2), valid results would be
(4), (4,2), and (2).
Would not be
(4,4) (2,2) or (2,4)

*eta*
(4,2,2) should return (2,2) as well.

Length is not pre-determined.

What I have right now:

```
def gen_all_partials(outcomes, length):
    """
    Iterative function that enumerates the set of all sequences of
    outcomes of lengths up to given length.
    """

    answer_set = set([()])
    for dummy_idx in range(length):
        temp_set = set()
        for partial_sequence in answer_set:
            for item in outcomes:
                new_sequence = list(partial_sequence)
                new_sequence.append(item)
                temp_set.add(tuple(new_sequence))
        answer_set = temp_set
    return answer_set
```

This is partially obtained by a given function. I don't understand how Python is iterating over an empty set in that 2nd "for" loop. This current code outputs (4,4), (2,2), and (2,4) in addition to the "right" answers.

I'm getting hung up on the nested loops and keeping track of multiple counters and having different lengths for the desired output.

I have also tried this:

```
def gen_all_partials(outcomes, length):
    """
    Iterative function that enumerates the set of all sequences of
    outcomes of lengths up to given length.
    """

    answer_set = set([()])
    for dummy_idx in range(length):
        temp_set = set()
        for partial_sequence in answer_set:
            for item in outcomes:
                new_sequence = list(partial_sequence)
                new_sequence.append(item)
                if new_sequence not in temp_set:
                    temp_outcomes = list(outcomes[:])
                    add_to_set = True
                    for val in new_sequence:
                        if val in temp_outcomes:
                            order_list = []
                            for dummy_bit in val:
                                order_list.append(val.index(dummy_bit)) 
                                if order_list == order_list.sort():
                                    temp_outcomes.remove(val)
                                else:
                                    add_to_set = False
                        else: 
                            add_to_set = False
                    if add_to_set:
                        temp_set.add(tuple(new_sequence))
        answer_set = temp_set
    return answer_set
```

Comment: If you are allowed to use the standard library, this would be only a few lines with the use of `itertools`. If not, I strongly suggest that you write some wrapper functions instead of nesting that deep. It becomes confusing.

Comment: Your definition of "in order" seems different to mine - what should happen for e.g. `(1, 2, 3)`?

Comment: (1,2,3) should return (1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (1), (2), (3), and (1,2,3) but not (2,3,1) or (2,1).

Comment: Oh, I see - the *elements* in the subset must be in the right order. That's standard; I thought you were being required to provide the subsets in some specific order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way, using recursion, though you can alternatively do it iteratively with a loop, and join the lists for each `n`:

```
a = [4,2]

def subseqs(x):
    def go(x, n):
        return zip(*(x[i:] for i in range(n))) + go(x, n-1) if n else []
    return go(x, len(x))

print subseqs(a)   # [(4, 2), (4,), (2,)]
```

or using a list comprehension:

```
print sum([zip(*(a[i:] for i in range(n))) for n in range(len(a)+1)], [])
```

Comment: This is so much closer than I was. I should have included an example with some duplicates - (4,2,2) should also return (2,2).

Comment: For [4,2,2] this code will return [(4, 2, 2), (4, 2), (2, 2), (4,), (2,), (2,)] - what result are you looking for?

Comment: Dangit, you're right. I need to figure out how to get (2,2) back for [2,4,2]

Answer (score 3):

From the ever-helpful [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

This includes the empty set, but you can trivially alter the `range` to handle that.

Comment: I believe in this case `itertools` is against the spirit of the exercise :)

Comment: @timgeb I'm a firm believer in standing on the giants' shoulders!

Comment: This is super helpful for reality-land, but unfortunately, will not work for this assignment. :(  Actually, the empty set should be included ultimately, but I was calling this function from another one that added the empty set so I didn't include it.

Comment: @AaronHall only three, apparently.

Comment: @mauve note that the `itertools` documentation includes equivalent implementations of both [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), so you don't necessarily have to `import` anything.