# partial subsets again - running into generator objects instead of results

Tags: python, python-2.7

Thanks to the [links to itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) jonrsharpe gave me in response to my [previous attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618318/generate-partial-subsets-in-python), I have a new strategy, which is to adjust those functions to conform with my requirements (hence "dummy" and longer counter names and such). Unfortunately, I'm now getting (both in Spyder and the web-based submission format I need to submit in) this result:

```
[<generator object combinations_of_options>]
```

instead of the actual values. I'm at a loss. How do I get back the actual results instead of a pointer to the result?

```
def from_list(some_list):
'''turns an interable into individual elements'''
    for dummy in some_list:
        for element in dummy:
            yield element

def combinations_of_options(options, length):
    ''' yields all combinations of option in specific length
    '''
    pool = tuple(options)
    pool_len = len(pool)
    if length > pool_len:
        return
    indices = range(length)
    yield tuple(pool[index] for index in indices)
    while True:
        for index in reversed(range(length)):
            if indices[index] != index + pool_len - length:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[index] += 1
        for dummy_index in range(index+1, length):
            indices[dummy_index] = indices[dummy_index-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[index] for index in indices)

def gen_proper_subsets(outcomes):
    outcomes = list(outcomes)
    max_len = len(outcomes)
    values = [combinations_of_options(outcomes, max_len) for dummy in range(max_len+1)]
    print values
    return from_list(values)
```

in/out desired:
in (4,2,2)
out (4,2,2), (4,2), (2,2), (4,), (2,), ()

in (2,4,2)
out (2,4,2), (2,4), (4,2), (2,2), (4,), (2,), ()

Comment: Comment out the `print` and try `list(gen_proper_subsets([1, 2, 3]))` - although it doesn't work, it *is* producing outputs.

Comment: Thanks! That at least fixed that specific problem in Spyder. The browser-based is giving me other trouble now. But new trouble is progress, amirite?

Comment: Yep, keep fixing little problems until you don't get any!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling your `combinations_of_outcomes()` function does indeed return a generator, which you must iterate over to extract the values. Perhaps instead of

```
values = [combinations_of_options(outcomes, max_len) for dummy in range(max_len+1)]
```

you might try

```
values = [list(combinations_of_options(outcomes, max_len)) for dummy in range(max_len+1)]
```

It looks as though at present `max_len` has a value of zero, so you are only seeing one generator in your result. After this change you will see one list element of the containing list.

Comment: Actually, "list" did fix the generator problem. The "proper results" problem is now visible!